# Float arredondando em C

Tags: c, float

Preciso retornar um valor **float** com 1 casa decimal, porém está voltando com o valor arredondado.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
float n1 = 4;
float n2 = 9;

float total = n2 / n1 ;

printf("Media: %.1f ", total ); //aqui, o resultado é 2.3

printf("Media: %.2f", total); //aqui, o resultado é 2.25
```

O valor esperado deveria ser `Média = 2.2`, mas está retornando `2.3`.

Existe alguma solução?

Comment: Ótima pergunta `+1`

Answer (score 6):

```
float n1 = 4;
float n2 = 9;

float total = n2 / n1 ;
float truncado = floor( total * 10.0f ) / 10.0f;

printf("Media: %.1f ", truncado );
printf("Media: %.2f ", truncado );
printf("Media: %.5f ", truncado );
```

> Altere os dois `10.0f` da forma que desejar. Por exemplo, `1000.0f` para 3 casas.

Tecnicamente o que você mencionou é um truncamento (ou arredondamento para menor), em vez de arredondamento tradicional (4/5), que é o comportamento do `%.1f`.

Caso deseje uma resposta mais específica, diga o critério desejado (ex: arredondar para par, truncar para o maior, usar arredondamento 4/5, usar arredondamento 5/6, etc).

[Clique aqui](http://ideone.com/XhVDyM) e veja o código em funcionamento no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/XhVDyM)**.

Comment: Bacco, o problema está no valor que está voltando arredondado. Eu não quero que arredonde

Comment: @Tercio lembre-se de que você pode usar o `truncado` apenas na hora de exibir na tela, se preferir, e continuar usando o `total` para outras coisas. Se precisar de algum detalhe a mais, explique aqui que eu posso tentar incrementar a resposta.

Comment: @Bacco O que acha de `printf("Media: %.2f\b ", total);`? O `\b` resolve, mas não sei se é uma solução segura.

Comment: @LucasNunes eu não arriscaria, depende muito do dispositivo de saída (imagine um redirect pra arquivo, por exemplo). E de repente ele pode querer usar o valor em uma interface gráfica depois, aí a solução não funcionaria. Eu gosto da idéia de usar a variável por outro motivo também, se ele precisar fazer somas, o total vai bater com o que foi mostrado na tela (mas, é claro, são apenas hipóteses).